# Constraining autoencoder embedding to be integer only in keras

Tags: keras, autoencoder

I have a set of 10 variables. I would like to find the best encoding of combinations of these variables as a single integer between 0 and 10 (yes, I know this will not be a particularly good embedding).

I can create an autoencoder with a hidden layer with size 1 in keras, but is it possible to somehow constrain the model so that values in this layer will have to be integers?

Comment: Please give a minimal code example that shows where exactly you want to have integers only, as this is not at all clear to me from your description.

Comment: Keras is gradient based optimizer and what you describe does not seem to be  differentiable. So it is not possible unless you could find/define a differentiable approximation for `round()` function.

Comment: It seems you might be able to train the model using **float** parameters and then **discretize** and **quantize** the output.